# Which systems memory will be used by ssis package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have few questions about the memory usage in ssis package.

1. If i am loading data from server A to Server B and the ssis package is in my desktop System and running through BIDS,Whether the buffer creation(memory usage) will happen in my desktop system?If this is the case,the performance(low memory compare to servers) will be slow right?
2. How to enable the usage of server resources while developing package in my desktop system?
3. Please help me, if i have 3 ssis developer and all are developing different packages at a time,What is the best development method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. A package runs on the same computer as the program that launches it. Even when a program loads a package that is stored remotely on another server, the package runs on the local computer.
2. If by server resources you mean server CPU, you cant. Is like using resources of any other computer on the network. Of course, if you have an OleDBSource that runs a select on SQL server, the CPU that "runs" the select will be the one on SQL Server, obviously, but once the resultset is retrieved, it is handled by the computer where the package is running.
3. Like any other development method. If you have a class on a C# project being developed by 3 developer, how do you do it? You can have each developer working on the same file and merge the changes, after all a package is a xml file, but is more complicated. I wouldn't recommend. I've been on situations where more than one developer worked on the same package but not at the exact same time.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on #3, the best way I have found to allow teams to work on a single SSIS solution is to decompose a problem (package) down into smaller and smaller chunks and control their invocation through a parent-child/master-slave type relationship.

For example, the solution concerns loading the data warehouse. I'd maybe have 2 Controller packages, FactController.dtsx and DimensionController.dtsx. Their responsibility is to call the various packages that solve the need (loading facts or dimensions). Perhaps my DimensionProductLoader package is dealing with a snowflake (it needs to update the Product and the SubProduct table) so that gets decomposed into 2 packages.

The goal of all of this is to break the development process down into manageable chunks to avoid concurrent access to a single package. Merging the XML will not be a productive use of your time.

The only shared resource for all of this is the SSIS project file (dtproj) which is just an XML document enumerating the packages that compromise the project. Create an upfront skeleton project with well-named, blank packages and you can probably skip some of the initial pain surrounding folks trying to merge the project back into your repository. I find that one-off type of merges go much better, for TFS at least, than everyone checking their XML globs back in.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Diego's and Bill's Answers:

1) Diego has this mostly correct, I would just add:  The package runs on the computer that runs it, but even worse, running a package through BIDS is not even close to what you will see on a server since the process BIDS uses to run the package is a 32bit process running local.  You will be slower due to limits related to running in the 32bit subsystem, as well as copying all of your data for the buffer across the network to the buffer in memory on your workstation, transforming it as your package flows, and then pushing it again across the network to your destination server.  This is fine for testing small subsets of your data in a test environment, but should not be used to estimate the performance on a server system.

2) Diego has this correct. If you want to see server performance, deploy it to a test server and run it there.

3) billinkc has this correct. One of the big drawbacks to SSIS in TFS is that there is not an elegant way to share work on a single package.  If you want to use more than one developer in a single process break it into smaller chunks and let only one developer work on each piece. As long as they are not developing the same package at the same time, you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for all the confirmations, +1 because you added good info on item 1

Comment: And 32 bit or not, running within BIDS/SSDT wraps the process with the debugger further slowing it down. A more accurate test (memory, throughput, etc) would be to invoke the package from the command line (dtexec /file C:\path\to\myPackage.dtsx)